# Is 'you' acceptable here, or should it be 'he'?

Tags: personal-pronouns, indefinite-pronouns

Jonas found a job as a newspaper boy, when you could find a boy selling newspapers on every corner.

Is 'you' here acceptable or does it need to be changed to 'he'? I see it as a matter of everyone being able to see, rather than just Jonas being able to see.

Comment: "....when you could find...." is fine.  You could also say "...when one could find....", but personally, I find "one" stilted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either "*one*" or "*you*" fits here, but "*he*" does not fit, semantically.

It is not grammatically incorrect to use "*he*" here, but that gives a different meaning from what is no doubt intended.

If you used "*he*" then people would understand it as referring to Jonas. The point is not that Jonas would have seen boys selling newspapers on corners everywhere. The point is that back then **anyone** (*you*, *one*) would have seen that.

Comment: I am confused. You answer _No_ to the question _Is 'you' acceptable?_ and then say that _"you"_ fits. I understand the point, but isn't the _No_ contradictory?

Comment: I was referring to "*or does it need to be changed to 'he'?*". I've removed the "*No*" from the start of the sentence, so the answer should be clearer now. Thx.

Comment: Thanks, guys! I thought the 'he' was odd as well, but felt it was possible to say from the character's vantage.